# How to list files with small char file names?

Tags: bash

A folder has these files: 1ABC.txt, 1abc.txt ....
How to do ls to list abc.txt and other small char filename only ?

```
ls 1a*.txt
```

...works, but this doesn't:

```
ls 1[a-z]*.txt
```

Comment: That said, Stack Overflow is for *software development* questions. Questions about using UNIX tools are better fit for [unix.se] or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: BTW, post code **as text**, not images.

Comment: `1[a-z]*.txt` is a glob, not a regex. Well, it's _also_ a valid regex, but it means two different things depending on whether you use it somewhere it's treated as a glob or a regex, and in bash, it's a glob.

Comment: Would you mind asking it in the other place *this time?* You can delete and repost it on the correct site. Off topic is off topic.

Comment: ...if my answer is preventing you from deleting the question, let me know and I'll delete it.

Comment: "You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it." @CharlesDuffy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an [extglob](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern):

```
shopt -s extglob
ls 1+([[:lower:]]).txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include names that contains numbers and other non-alpha characters, then you just negate the `[:upper:]` class name:

```sh
shopt -s extglob
ls +([^[:UPPER:]])
```

This is still shorter than including the positive character classes like this:

```sh
shopt -s extglob
ls +([[:LOWER:][:BLANK:][:SPACE:][:CNTRL:][:DIGIT:][:GRAPH:][:PUNCT:]])
```

Answer (score -1):

This seems to work for me (on WSL. please don't shoot me...)

```
ls | grep -v -E '[[:upper:]]'
```

Comment: The problem with this is that trying to write software with it runs afoul of all the bugs described in [ParsingLs](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: So, bad idea I guess if you have newlines in your filenames...but I'm sure there are situations were it could be useful.

Comment: In none of those situations does there not exist an alternative that avoids the bugs.